# Kill wifi connection

Tags: daemon, wpa-supplicant, processes

I am trying to debug my wifi which does not work so I want to stop wpa_suppliciant and apply the -d option

If I first

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

Then

```
ps -A | grep wpa
```

returns a new pid

I am on

```
Linux r4 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:12 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: You need to figure out who is bringing it up - eg NetworkManager, wicd, whatever - and stop that (can't tell you more because I don't have ubuntu at hand).

Comment: loreb's right, so I edited your title to more precisely reflect the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you kill WPA_supplicant a new instance is created by your connection manager.

You have to disable it before running the kill command.
To disable the connection manager you need to stop the related service (I.e. network-manager, wicd, etc..) using the command:

```
service CONNECTION_MANAGER stop
```

Changing the string CONNECTION_MANAGER with the real service name.

After that you can execute the command you wrote but using an handwritten config file. You can use the command

```
man wpa_supplicant.conf
```

to find examples or documentation about the configuration file.